# Select @Script returns NULL instead of @Script SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having a bit of trouble with the following query:

```
DECLARE
    @Type TINYINT = NULL,
    @ErrorDescription VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL

SELECT @Type

DECLARE @Script VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SET @Script =
    'DECLARE @Type TINYINT = ' + CAST(@Type AS VARCHAR(10)) +'
    DECLARE @ErrorDescription VARCHAR(MAX) = ' + CASE WHEN @Type = 1 THEN '''' + @ErrorDescription + '''' ELSE 'NULL' END 

SELECT @Script
```

My `@Type` will be one of three values: Null, 0, 1

Null - Begin Process
0 - Succeeded process
1 - Errored Process

For 0 I get the result:

| @Type |
| --- |
| 0 |

| @Script |
| --- |
| DECLARE @Type TINYINT = 0 DECLARE @ErrorDescription VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL |

For `NULL` and 1 I get `NULL` in the `@Script`.

| @Script |
| --- |
| NULL |

I need `NULL` and 1 to return `@Script`'s result like 0 did.

I checked if the conversion of `@Type` to `Varchar(10)` was the problem, but it has no effect.

I've removed the apostrophes but that either returned an error or same result.

I changed `@ErrorDescription` to be 'This is an error' and that returned the proper result for 1 but not `NULL`.

Thanks in advance!

I've searched the internet for questions like mine but I saw a jQuery question and questions asking how to get NULL as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interchange `NULL` for meaning `'unknown'`

When you concatenate `unknown` to a string, the result is also `unknown` (if you add an unknown quantity to a known quantity you now have an unknown quantity). You need to use `IsNull()`

try

```
+ CAST(isnull(@Type,'0') AS VARCHAR(10)) +
```

Comment: This is so close! 
The problem is NULL, 0, and 1 mean something so changing it to 0 might break the process.
Null - Begin Process
0 - Succeeded process
1 - Errored Process
Sorry for not mentioning it before. I added it to the question

Comment: Having `null` represent an actual state is an antipattern - if your process is known to be at the "begin" phase, that is not unknown, it is known, you would find it much easier to just not deal with `null` if you don't have to. However it seems you need to pass the null into your script? `+ IsNull(Cast(@Type AS VARCHAR(10)),'null') +`?

Comment: Is some tag missing? Like jquery? I've never heard of `unknown` in tsql